# How to convert a list to json in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, for-loop

have a list with values

```
test = ["mark","will","john"]
```

using for loop how to convert this into JSON like this

```
test =[{"name":"mark"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"will"}]
```

Tried this

```
for i in test :
    print({"name":i})
```

Comment: does your list only contains names or any other values you want to convert it into json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a dictionary within a list comprehension:

```
test = ["mark","will","john"]
json_list = [{"name": n} for n in test]
```

same as:

```
json_list = []
for n in test:
    json_list.append({"name" : n})
```

then dump to `json`:

```
import json
json.dumps(json_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json

test =[{"name":"mark"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"will"}]

testJson = json.dumps(test)

print(testJson)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

functional way using `map()`

```
test = ["mark", "will", "john"]

toJson = lambda _name: {"name": _name} # this expression returns {"name": name} for every iterated "_name"

testJson = map(toJson, test)

for name in testJson:
  print(name)
```

to print a list of a map object cast it to list, example `list(testJson)`
and you can replace `toJson` with your `lambda` expression to customize the result

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> test = ["mark","will","john"]
>>> final=[]
>>> for i in test:
    d=dict()
    d['name']=i
    final.append(d)
>>> final

>>>[{'name': 'mark'}, {'name': 'will'}, {'name': 'john'}]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.